# Connecting custom values to button and passing them to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I have a modal(using bootstrap 4 for react). And I want for two buttons to pass value to binded functions. How can I do this?

Here is my code

this is component

```
<Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            <WeatherInfo
              nameOfCity={nameOfCity}
              weatherDescription={weatherDescription}
              windSpeed={windSpeed}
              temperature={temperature}
              maxTemperature={maxTemperature}
              minTemperature={minTemperature}
              isChec={isChec}
              change={this.toggleCheckboxChange.bind(this)}
            />
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={function(){this.addToMyCityList.bind(this); this.toggle()}}>Add City</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="primary" onClick={function(){this.removeFromMyCityList.bind(this); this.toggle()}}>Remove City</Button>{' '}
            </ModalFooter>
          </Modal>
```

and these are the functions that should get value

```
  addToMyPCityList(e) {
    this.props.dispatch(mPkArrayAdd(e.target.nameOfCity.value))
  }

  removeFromMyCityList(e) {
    this.props.dispatch(mPkArrayRemove(e.target.nameOfCity.value))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```js
<Button color="primary" onClick={function(e){this.addToMyCityList(e, myParam); this.toggle()}}>Add City</Button>

addToMyCityList(e, myParam) {}
```